# Быстрая запись данных в файл на python

Tags: python, запись

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста,  есть ли быстрый способ записать 250 000 или более строк в файл txt? Мой скрипт на python генерирует 65000 строк за 0.4сек, но если я буду построчно записывать их в файл, весь процесс занимает уже 20сек. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: 1) Желательно быстрое "железо" иметь (у вас не HDD, надеюсь:-))? 2) И как долго скрипт работает? Если не постоянно, может в виртуальный файл в ОЗУ писать временно, а копировать на более медленный носитель по завершении?

Comment: 1) Этот момент нужно уточнить у меня и hdd и ssd, и вобще как я сам не обратил на это внимание?? Спасибо, за этот вопрос)). 2) Скрипт сейчас работает до заполнения файла до 25-30млн строк. Можете скетч на запись в ОЗУ чиркануть? У меня была мысль заливать не каждую строку а копить хотя-бы по 10 000 в какую то переменную и потом записывать. Это реально?

Comment: Я не посоветую конкретно. Надо пробовать на вашем конкретном железе и ПО. См. также ответ.

Comment: Без кода ничего конкретного сказать нельзя, покажите его (может вы что-то  делаете неправильно). Еще важно какой размер строки, а так же фиксированный он или нет, и еще общий объем данных. Протестируйте (как конкретно зависит от вашей ОС) вначале "сырую" производительность диска, т.е. максимально возможную скорость при последовательной записи - это тот предел, который в идеале на даном оборудовании вы можете получить.

Answer (score 0):

За это придется заплатить памятью. Соберите одну строку с помощью join и переносов, запишите ее одну в файл

Comment: Не совсем вас понимаю. Вы предлагаете собрать сгенерированные 65000 строк в одну и её залить в файл?

Comment: А почему не попробовать? Если не все 65000, то сколько система позволит.

Comment: Спасибо!  проведу эксперимент.

Answer (score 0):

Упорядочу, что могу посоветовать:

Задача относительно стандартная. Лучше всего поискать конкретные алгоритмы действий в интернете.
При действиях самостоятельных (без поиска) я бы:

1. Решил, что является  ключевыми требованиями и каковы их приоритеты относительно друг друга?
   Я вижу в порядке приоритета:
   a) Быстродействие;
   б) Надежность хранения на случай сбоя по питанию;
   в) Стоимость.

2. Настроил запись на окончательный вывод на наиболее быстрый носитель (например, SDD, а не HDD).
3. Временно писал бы в ОЗУ сколько влезет, а потом сохранял бы на более медленный постоянный носитель (SSD).
   Конкретный метод записи в ОЗУ, объем и т.д. проверял натурными экспериментами (т.е. просто пробовал бы варианты. "Лучшая модель кошки- кошка".)

Comment: Можете посоветовать какой-то скетч по обращению с буфером?

Comment: Нет. Ищите статьи тех, кто реально с этим работает. У меня это все общая логика, никогда такую задачу не надо было решать.

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет! Как обычно бывает, если долго мучиться- что-то да получится. Пришёл к решению, что совершать запись огромного количества строк в моём случае не обязательно и гораздо быстрее обрабатывать полученные строки на лету. Таким образом если на момент создания темы, за 12 часов я получал ~30млн строк для последующей обработки, то сейчас обходя стороной процессы записи-чтения я получаю и сразу одрабатываю ~150млн.Длинна строки фиксированная и состоит из 70 символов.